# Send Email using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, email

I made a little application to send email with attemet using spring boot, at the first it works, then I had port problem :

> "Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1"

I tried to change the port to `"465"`.
But I have found the same problem.
What's the matter?
Thanks

Comment: Please add code part

Answer (score 0):

I`m using spring-boot-starter-mail 2.0.4.RELEASE in this code.

I use this Configuration for smtp.gmail.com.

```
@Configuration
public class EmailSenderConfig {

    @Value("${mail.login}")
    private String login;

    @Value("${mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername(login); //login for google account "this.my.email@gmail.com" 
        mailSender.setPassword(password); // password for google account "thisMyPassword666"

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

And this code for sending messages

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void sendToken(String to) {
    SimpleMailMessage smm = new SimpleMailMessage();

    String token = String.valueOf(new Random().ints(MIN, MAX).findFirst().getAsInt());

    verificationService.saveTemporaryToken(to, token);

    smm.setTo(to);
    smm.setSubject(TITLE);
    smm.setText(token);

    mailSender.send(smm);
}
```

Compare my code and your, maybe you forgot to write something.